# Creating an array with a single staggered values in each row?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate an nX3 array of zeros but one of the columns has the value (1.0) staggered in each row.

Desired Output:

```
n = 10
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I tried to slice and reshape an array but some rows contain all zeros.

My Attemtp:

```
n = 10
verts_color = np.zeros(3 * n)
verts_color[::4] = 1
verts_color.reshape((n,3))
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

I couldn't find an example or figure out how to solve this myself and was hoping someone here might be able to help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

```
def broadcasting_based(n, m): # n :number of cols, m : number of rows
    return (np.mod(np.arange(m),n)[:,None] == np.arange(n)).astype(float)
```

**Approach #2**

```
def tile_based(n, m): # n :number of cols, m : number of rows
    M = 1+((m-1)//n)
    return np.tile(np.eye(n),M).T[:m]
```

**Approach #3**

```
def initialization_based(n, m): # n :number of cols, m : number of rows
    M = 1+((m-1)//n)
    r = np.arange(n)
    out = np.zeros((M,n,n))
    out[:,r,r] = 1
    out.shape = (-1,n)
    return out[:m]
```

One more initialization based, a shorter one and making use of stepsize to slice -

```
def initialization_based_v2(n, m): # n :number of cols, m : number of rows
    out = np.zeros((m,n))
    for i in range(n):
        out[i::n,i] = 1
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [93]: broadcasting_based(n=3, m = 10)
Out[93]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])

In [94]: np.allclose(broadcasting_based(3,10), tile_based(3,10))
Out[94]: True

In [95]: np.allclose(broadcasting_based(3,10), initialization_based(3,10))
Out[95]: True

In [162]: np.allclose(broadcasting_based(3,10), initialization_based_v2(3,10))
Out[162]: True
```

**Runtime test**

Other approaches -

```
# @kmario23's soln
def using_concatenate(m, n):
    return np.concatenate([np.identity(m)]* (n//m + 1), axis=0 )[:n, :]

# @Michael's soln    
def initialization_modassign(m, n):
    x = np.zeros((n,m))
    i = np.arange(n)
    x[i, i%m] = 1
    return x
```

Timings -

```
In [188]: %timeit broadcasting_based(3,10000)
     ...: %timeit tile_based(3,10000)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based(3,10000)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based_v2(3,10000)
     ...: %timeit using_concatenate(3,10000)
     ...: %timeit initialization_modassign(3,10000)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 225 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.9 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.6 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.7 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 480 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 177 µs per loop

In [189]: %timeit broadcasting_based(5,10000)
     ...: %timeit tile_based(5,10000)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based(5,10000)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based_v2(5,10000)
     ...: %timeit using_concatenate(5,10000)
     ...: %timeit initialization_modassign(5,10000)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 238 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.6 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.3 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 176 µs per loop
```

So, on performance `initialization_based_v2` seems to be working quite well.

Comment: Your first post before your edit seemed to work perfectly when you wrote the line like `(np.mod(np.arange(n),3)[:,None] == np.arange(3)).astype(int)`

Comment: @divakar But, I'm still wondering how could a python `for` loop achieves such competitive performance.

Comment: @kmario23 Its iterating on `n`, where `n` is just `3`, so effectively as good as vectorized one.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit quirky but it works by realizing the fact that you've (vertically) stacked identity arrays but you need to adjust the rows based on `n`

```
n = 10
np.vstack([np.identity(3)]* (n//3 + 1))[:n, :]
```

Alternatively, you can use `np.concatenate` if you want improved performance:

```
np.concatenate([np.identity(3)]* (n//3 + 1), axis=0 )[:n, :]
```

For a ***general use case & improved performance*** use the following where `(n, m)` are the rows and columns respectively.

```
np.concatenate([np.identity(m)]* (n//m + 1), axis=0 )[:n, :]
```

Example:

```
In [151]: n = 10

In [152]: np.vstack([np.identity(3)]* (n//3 + 1))[:n, :]
Out[152]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])


# number of columns
In [170]: m = 3

# number of rows
In [171]: n = 10

In [172]: np.concatenate([np.identity(m)]* (n//m + 1), axis=0 )[:n, :]
Out[172]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

Performance:

```
In [176]: def using_concatenate(n, m):
     ...:     return np.concatenate([np.identity(m)]* (n//m + 1), axis=0 )[:n, :]
     ...: 

In [177]: %timeit using_concatenate(n, m)
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.8 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
x = np.zeros((n,3))
i = np.arange(n)
x[i, i%3] = 1
```

Comment: Very nice, this one didn't come across me!

Comment: Thank you. I don't know about the performance compared to the other solutions, but it's pretty short ;)

Comment: Added timings for all approaches in my post, if you want to check out.